# How to add zeros after decimal point

Tags: c#, decimal

Lets assume that I have decimal like this:

```
decimal a= 12.1
```

But I want it to be :

```
a=12.10
```

is it possible to make it without using `.toString()?`
I tried using `decimal.Round()` but this still sets a`=12.1`

**Clarification:**
the data eg. 12.1 is received from webservice so I can not simple change it to the 12.10M

Comment: As I know - no. The only way is using .toString().

Comment: The `decimal` type is designed to allow you to work with numeric data. As numbers, 12.10 and 12.1 are *exactly* the same, and so the decimal data type hasn't been designed to distinguish between the two. You either need to convert to strings or separately track how many decimal places you want to show.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Actually, the `decimal` type does include this information. The problem with szpic's code is that he's not using a decimal literal - when the double value `12.10` is cast to decimal, the zeroes are lost. Using `12.10M` works just fine :)

Comment: I updated my question with small clarification why I'm having 12.1 instead of literal 12.10

Comment: You shouldn't be concerned as to whether the *decimal* has a .0 or not, you should only be concerned with its string representation

Comment: @szpic That's also handled in my answer - just round to whatever you need and multiply by `1.00M`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Actually, .NET's `decimal` type does include zeroes after decimal point. You just have to use a decimal literal:

```
var a = 12.10M;
```

If you need this for real-time values rather than compile-time, you can multiply with another decimal literal, for example:

```
var a = someDecimalInput;
return a * 1.0000M; // Ensures at least four digits after the decimal point.
```

However, I'd still advise against this - formatting is better left to the presentation layer, and that's where you want to handle how many decimal points to display. You'd usually use something like `a.ToString("f2")`.

Comment: The implementation of decimal.ToString: return Number.FormatDecimal(this, null, NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo) this what the debugger calls to display a decimal's value

Comment: @ServéLaurijssen Yeah, that's what I'd expect - it looks like the debugger isn't actually using `ToString` for decimals, because `a.ToString()` shows the zeroes, while the debugger apparently doesn't. That's fine, the debugger can do whatever the hell it pleases, and there's definitely ways to modify that output regardless of `ToString` implementation :D

Comment: of course the implementation of decimal.ToString() cannot call decimal.ToString() :)